# How to block connections to a port opened by my applicaiton?

Tags: c#, sockets, air, interop

I have an application(Developed using Adobe AIR) in which i have opened a port and listening for incoming request from a specific application(other .net application). I have to accept the requests only from the local machine and not from any other machine. So, I have specified 127.0.0.1 as my Host Address and 9999 as my port number while creating the server socket.

My application is working fine. But the question is, Other computers are able to see this port which is open by my application? If they are able to see, How can we block the connection to my open port from other computers? Any suggestions to handle this issue?

Comment: Using firewall may be your answer.

Comment: Yes. Firewall blocking access to the specified PC port. (In your case, 9999).
Then the port is guaranteed to be local-access only (though listening on 127.0.0.1 does the same thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your server, put the local address to "127.0.0.1" for listening. This should prevent other computers in the network to be able to address the listener.